# Regex optional parantheses into forced three groups

Tags: regex, parentheses

I have a string full of parentheses like this:

```
(this) (should) (be) (group) (one) (thisshouldbegrouptwo) (this) (should) (be) (group) (three)
```

I'd like to regex this into three groups, with the constant string `thisshouldbegrouptwo`, optionally in parentheses, delimiting the groups:

```
1. Group: (this) (should) (be) (group) (one)
2. Group: (thisshouldbegrouptwo)
3. Group: (this) (should) (be) (group) (three)
```

The string `(thisshouldbegrouptwo)` is a fixed optional string, with its parentheses also optional. If it isn't present, I expect the following result:

```
1. Group: (this) (should) (be) (group) (one)
2. Group: 
3. Group: (this) (should) (be) (group) (three)
```

In this case, it would also be OK if the whole string was matched in a single group.

The number of parentheses for group 1 or 3 are not significant, only the parentheses around the middle group matter, and should be with the middle group if found, not with the edge groups.

This is my regular expression so far ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/0CCPQI/2)):

```
(\(.*\))?(?:\s(\(thisshouldbegrouptwo\)\s))?(\(.*\))
```

Comment: Can you explain your actual requirements better? How do you know what the groups are? The specific text in them? the presence or absence of whitespace? As asked, we really don't have enough to work from, and your demo doesn't really help. Maybe you could spell out in what way your demo is not doing what you want? It is also good practice to give the regex you're working on in the question itself, not just in a demo link.

Comment: The first group should be everything before (thisshouldbegrouptwo), the second group should be (thisshouldbegrouptwo) itself, and the third group everything after (thisshouldbegrouptwo). The problem is, that it is not ensured, that there is that before or after (thisshouldbegrouptwo). But I have to ensure, that the matched groups are always the same.

Comment: By that description, `(.*)(\(?thisshouldbegrouptwo\)?)(.*)` would do. I suspect your have more requirements in mind. We cannot help you unless you tell us in what way that's not enough.

Comment: Sorry, because of my limited english speaking knowledge it's hard for the to describe.

Comment: This example does work, als long (thisshouldbegrouptwo) is present. But there could be the case, that this is not present in the string. then I need a match for the complete full line in one group. In this example, this would result in no match.

Comment: When the middle part is missing, how do you know where the first part ends and the third parts starts?

Comment: in this case it would be ok to match the full line in the first group

Comment: OK, then how about `(.*?)(\(?thisshouldbegrouptwo\)?)?(.*)`? When the middle group is not there, I think everything will end up in the third group, though, not the first. No, it doesn't work. Let me work on it a bit more...

Comment: Here: `(.*?)(\(?thisshouldbegrouptwo\)?)(.*)|(.*)` When group 2 is there, groups 1, 2 and 3 have what you want; when it's not, group 4 has everything.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd post it as an answer if I could, but the question is still closed. There are two reopen votes so far, so it might yet get reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will do what you want:

```
(.*?)(\(?thisshouldbegrouptwo\)?)(.*)|(.*)
```

When `thisshouldbegrouptwo` is present in the string, groups 1 and 3 will have the left and right context, excluding the optional parentheses that might surround group 2.

When that text is not present in the string, group 4 will contain the entire string.

Keys elements of the solution:

- Using a non-greedy expression first, `.*?` instead of `.*`, avoids have the opening parenthesis of group 2 lumped into group 1 instead.
- The `|(.*)` at the end is a catch-all, but since regular expressions are processed from left to right, you'll get the first part matching when the group two string is present.

I could not find a solution that separated the non-matching case into two groups, since there is nothing to divide them in that case, but since you said it was OK to keep it together, moving it to group 4 as this expression does should work for you.